# Activate Dialog Box after returning back the control

Tags: mfc, winapi

The problem is i am calling one dialox from another dialox , and after returning back from that dialog box the dialog window is not enabled. in order to activate it i have to click  anywhere is dialog. so how can i get the focus on this current dialog window after returning from other dialog box.

Comment: The problem is only occur, if the size of next dialog is larger then the parent dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try:

this->SetFocus();

after the other box has returned.

Comment: i tried but it is not working. even i tried with SetForegroundWindow() also... but not worth it ...

Comment: Is it possible to  provide code from the function that calls the other dialog?